# How can I append a field to the body field?

Tags: theming, 9

I have a content type (*Press releases*) with three fields: *field_date*, *field_location*, and *body*.

I am trying to create a template override for this content type based on this design.

> [image: screenshot]

As you can see in the image, the date and location fields are appended to the body field.

I have tried adding all the fields in a single `<div>` and setting its `display` property to `inline`, but nothing has happened.

This is the code from the template override.

```html
<div class="press-releases-body">
  {{content.field_release_date}}
  {{content.field_location}}
  {{ content.body }}
</div>
```

Comment: What template is this?  If the layout is affected by CSS/HTML you don't want, it's likely that your template is picking up other templates "down the chain" (for example, a node type template is pulling in field templates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a formatted text field I would append the field data in a preprocess hook so that you can add the text within the enclosing field template and also remove the `<p>` tag Ckeditor adds automatically to the content of the field:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node__press_releases(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if (isset($variables['content']['body'][0])) {
    $body = $variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'];
    $body = preg_replace(['#^<p>#', '#</p>$#'], '', $body);
    $date = $node->field_date->date ? $node->field_date->date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : '';
    $location = $node->field_location->value;
    $body = $date . ' - ' . $location . ' - ' . $body;
    $variables['content']['body'][0]['#text'] = $body;
  }
}
```

Then you don't need to configure the two appended fields in the display settings and it's not necessary to change the twig template.

Comment: the above solution is working for me

Comment: how to implement an empty check for the location and date field before running this code

Comment: I've already included a check for the date field to avoid a PHP error trying to run a method on NULL . The location value property returns NULL without error. For further logic you can then test both variables in `if (!empty(...)) {`

Answer (score 1):

Patrick Kenny is, most probably, right about templates "down the chain".

Copy `your_site_directory/sites/default/default.services.yml`

as `your_site_directory/sites/default/services.yml`

and modify it to enable twig debug:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

Clear the caches and inspect what templates you should target.